# How DetectionBoxes_Recall is calculated for values 1 / 10 / 100?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard, object-detection-api

When we are training Tensorflow Object Detection API, in Tensorboard there are 3 metrics for recall:

- 'DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@1': average recall with 1 detection.
- 'DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@10': average recall with 10 detections.
- 'DetectionBoxes_Recall/AR@100': average recall with 100 detections.

How are those calculated? What 'with n detections' exactly mean?

[image: graphs from TB]